# Mysql connection - is faster to connect via IP then domain?

Tags: php, mysql, dns, ip

**Question**

Is faster this

```
$servername = "125.125.55.10";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
```

or this?

```
$servername = "mysql.server.com";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
```

or it has no effect to speed?

I do not know if it has any practical use, but millisecond is milisecond....

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it could be considered slightly faster, as there is no need to resolve the domain to an IP address (DNS lookup). However, most modern technologies will cache the IP address when a connection is made, meaning a DNS lookup does not have to be made for every connection to the same address. So the difference is neglible, apart from the first time you connect to a site, and even then only for a few seconds at most.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to measure it?

Comment: The DNS lookup time? You can check the time to a server with a tool like http://network-speed.com/dnstime.php

Comment: Ah. I forget that's a thing.

Comment: @JamesPaterson I think your logic is right. IP doesn't need to resolve the domain. "most modern technologies will cache" that means modern technologies  also used cached ip.  Do you have idea about private network IP. Can we use that

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, the first time your web-server will access mysql-database, it will cache resolved hostname. 
The problem with using IPs is that it's basically hardcode, it's hard to grep, IP can change far more frequently then hostname, etc. 
More than that: spending your time on premature optimizations like

- connect using hostname/ip
- connect using unix socket/tcp socket
- use persistent connections or not?

is a waste of time, if your tables/scripts are not optimized.

what to look for in database (sql/nosql) performance:

- learn to use your dbms indexes / learn  "EXPLAIN query"
- never update huge number of rows one by one, update in batch-mode only
- while developing a project, generate a LOT (>500k of rows) of fake data and insert it to database, this way you will know when your 'perfect query' is slow before your production server suffers

Comment: Ok so its better to use hostname and focus on more impotant stuff, like using mysqli instead of PDO?

Comment: Yes, better to use hostname and focus on more important stuff. Use whatever you like - pdo/mysqli, they are both not deprecated. Don't focus on them, implementation details. Learn to use SQL / composer / frameworks.

Comment: Thank you, it's very helpfull.